# SSIS Duplicate Enumerators in ForEach Loop

Tags: visual-studio-2019, ssis-2012

I am using VS2019 Professional (v16.11.34) to create my SSIS packages.  I just recently started getting issues with my ForEach loops not executing (in development only, anything I've previously developed is running fine).

EDIT: this is the error I get with any new development in my ForEach loop:

[image]

I have noticed that when selecting an enumerator in my ForEach loop, I now have duplicate enumerators to choose from:
[image]

I have "repaired" Visual Studio, and "repaired" MSDT, but still this persists.

Has anyone else had this happen to them, and if so, how did you resolve it?